# Write a PHP program that reads a word and prints the word in reverse. For example, if the user provides the input "Harry", the program prints yrraH

Tags: php

Write a PHP program that reads a word and prints the word in reverse.  For example, if the user provides the input "Harry", the program prints yrraH.

I've been stuck on this problem for a while now. 
I was also given some tips on how to start off as given here;

**Hint: use a loop and the strlen() method for a string
strlen("Hello")  will yield the value 5 since Hello has 5 characters
Strings can also be treated like an array, so for instance:
$s = "Hello";
print $s[0];   // this would yield H  since H is in the 0 position of the string
Think about using a for loop that starts with the length of the string and counts backward.**

So far I've been going back and forth between the code but right now I can't even get myself to think of how to start the code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't dwell about how to start code when you're learning. I've always found is good just to get code down. *Expect* that you'll need to fix it later. Just get something down you you have code to work with. It's like writing an essay. Sitting there for an hour staring at the screen doesn't accomplish much.

Comment: Also, since you don't have code, you've made it very difficult for us to help you without doing the bulk of the work for you, which wouldn't help you any.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Looks like you need to learn more about what is expected of users here. You're expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: You don't need to roll your own when php already offers `strrev` http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php  Take some time to read through the entire list of string functions and consider all of the possibilities.  To learn, read the manual.  By posting this question you are distracting SO answerers that could be answering a real problem else where.  Please delete this question because it will have no value to future SO readers.

Comment: Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) as well as [this open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something to get you going:

### How it works

Since you're learning, here's a brief explanation of how it works.   First, assign our string to a variable (`$str`).  Next, we create a temporary string to store the reversed version of the string in, `$results`.  Next, we iterate through `$str` backwards, appending the character to `$results`.  Then we print out our results, `$results`.

```
<?php

$str = "Harry";
$results = "";

for ($i = strlen($str)-1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    $results .= $str[$i];
}

print($results);

?>
```

### There is also a built in function for this

I know your teacher probably won't appreciate this, but there is also a built in function for reversing function, `strrev`.

```
<?php

$str = "Harry";
print(strrev($str));

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, and also as a reply to the previous responses I did attempt the code before coming to post right away. I was just lost on where to start and only got as far as learning what "strlen" and a for loop was which was what was suggested by the professor. So to get the user's input for the program and have the end result reverse it, I would have to use a readline command from what I'm getting in the manual?

Comment: You can replace `$str = "Harry";` with `$str = readline("Enter a name: ");`.  Try that.

Comment: It worked perfectly, thanks so much for the help, little by little I'm learning this so this is much appreciated!